# Facebook Graph Api : og.follows not working return nothing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use the **og.follows** to follow any person or page on facebook but it is returning nothing just null.Here the link of **OG.FOLLOWS**  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.follows/

I am trying this link to follow a profile  :

**https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.follows?profile=https://www.facebook.com/[USERNAME_HERE]&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE]**

This is returning nothing!
I am using the access token with all permissions but I don't know where the actual problem is on my end or at other end ! I have also used the token ( Page Manger for IOS ) which have following permission i think but null ! So kindly tell me solution !

Comment: The URL to a Facebook user profile is not a proper Open Graph object. You need to create an object of type [`profile`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/profile/) yourself first.

Comment: you means this :
https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.follows?object=100003592581890&access_token=token_here

Comment: or profile instead of object ?

Comment: No, you need to pass an Open Graph object as the value for `profile` - so either the id or the URL of an object of that type that you created earlier.

Comment: can you please give me the  short link  of api

Comment: Check the link I posted.

Comment: here app_id I have to use the id of the app which token i am using ?

Comment: Yes. (Otherwise you will likely get errors saying the object does belong to a different app afterwards.)

Comment: Thanks Buddy <3 almost done :0 but now when I am trying to create object it says token is not acitve :( An active access token must be used to query information about the current user ! But my token is live and I have tried almost 4 types of app

Comment: What type of token is it?

Comment: can you give me the http of creating an object please sir :(

Comment: such as https://graphs.facebook.com/me/objects/ .... etc

Comment: The page I linked to has code samples describing how to create such an object.

Comment: I am searching from 3 hours and watched each single tut on youtube but can find a single link on which i can use token and follow other as we do in case of like please sir can you give me explanation please

Comment: sir? kindly answer please

Comment: @CBroe  ???????????????????????????????????????

Comment: There is no way to follow a person using the API.

Comment: ohh but I am using a site which are using token to follow open example is hublaa follower